# get nearest tens-place number above and below any number

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to be able to get the nearest x-tens-place number above and below any number using C#

For example, if I have a 4-digit number and I want all the closes number above and below ending and set of 2-digit number like 30, 50, 80, or 00 then

```
2126 => 2100 and 2130
2146 => 2130 and 2150
2183 => 2180 and 2200
```

I want to be able to do this below 1 too, like if my set of levels are 0.0030, 0.0050, 0.0080 and 0.0000 then if I had the following numbers

```
1.0026 => 1.0000 and 1.0030
1.0046 => 1.0030 and 1.0050
1.0083 => 1.0080 and 1.0100
```

The purpose of this is to calculate hi/lo ranges around a given asset price and a set of range values.

Comment: had you tried Math.Round?

Comment: yes i have, and Math.Ceiling(), the trick is to do it in a way that is generic to the number of decimal places in the range numbers and to round up/down to the correct tens-place.

Comment: then you need to create your own logic for it.

Comment: Why `2126 => 2100 and 2130` and not `2126 => 2120 and 2130` ?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - It's because this isn't actually 10's rounding. The OP is specifying the numbers to round to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this isn't really anything to do with 10's rounding you have to specify the number of digits that you want to truncate with and then iterate over the "set point" values to find the two closest points to the given input.

This is what I came up with:

```
Func<double, double[], int, double> lower = (x, sps, d) =>
    sps
        .Select(sp => sp + Math.Truncate(Math.Pow(10.0, d) * x) / Math.Pow(10.0, d))
        .Where(v => v <= x)
        .Last();

Func<double, double[], int, double> upper = (x, sps, d) =>
    sps
        .Select(sp => sp + Math.Truncate(Math.Pow(10.0, d) * x) / Math.Pow(10.0, d))
        .Where(v => v >= x)
        .First();
```

My input `data` is:

```
var data = new []
{
    new
    {
        setpoints = new double[] { 0, 30, 50, 80, 100 },
        digits = -2,
        values = new double[] { 2126, 2146, 2183 },
    },
    new
    {
        setpoints = new [] { 0.0, 0.003, 0.005, 0.008, 0.01 },
        digits = 2,
        values = new [] { 1.0026, 1.0046, 1.0083 },
    },
};
```

The results were calculated as:

```
var results =
    data
        .SelectMany(
            x => x.values,
            (x, v) => new
            {
                value = v,
                lower = lower(v, x.setpoints, x.digits),
                upper = upper(v, x.setpoints, x.digits)
            });
```

The results I got were as expected:

[image: results]